# Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." in Swift 3

Tags: php, json, swift3

I'm working on a project and below is my Swift code. But when I run that I get this error.

`Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}`

Also I check response from the database it says it has a valid content length. But because of this error I cannot get what I want.

From the response print in my code;

```
Optional(<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x608000233bc0> { URL: http://192.168.1.99/insertData.php } { status code: 200, headers {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Length" = 10;
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Wed, 13 Sep 2017 21:37:38 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=5, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian)";
} })`
```

This is my code.

```
let urlOfSMARTCF = URL(string: "http://192.168.1.99/insertData.php")
let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: urlOfSMARTCF! as URL)   request.httpMethod="POST"
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

for contact in contactsCaptuure
{
    let userMobileNumber = DBManager.shared.retriveRegisteredNumberOfMobile()    
    let postParameters = "\"usermobilenum\":\(String(describing: userMobileNumber!)),\"contactnum\":\(contact.phoneNumber!)";
    request.httpBody = postParameters.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest)
    {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil
        {
            print("error is \(String(describing: error))")
            return;
        }
        do
        {
            print(response)
            let myJSON = try  JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            if let parseJSON = myJSON
            {
                var msg : String!
                msg = parseJSON["message"] as! String?
                print(msg)

            }
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
            print(error)
        }

    }
    print("Done")
    task.resume()
}
```

So to complete my project I need to solve this.Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Sam response something like this

echo ('{"Response":[{"status":"fail"}]}');  or

echo ('{"Response":[{"status":"success"},{"userid":'.$userid.'}]}');

Try this and let us know please... :)